# IE compatibility with jQuery Tools Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, tooltip, jquery-tools

I've started designing a page using the jQuery Tools' tooltip ([as demonstrated here](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html)).

I've tinkered with it a bit to allow onClick show and onClick hide. Works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

But it won't work on IE 9, despite that jquery tools is meant to be VERY cross browser compatible.

The script I used is:

```
  $(function() {
      // initialize tooltip
      var tooltip = $("#cog").tooltip({
        tipClass: 'usermenu',
        effect: 'slide', 
        bounce: true, 
        direction: 'down', 
        slideOffset: 10, 
        offset: [-5,-38], 
        delay: 500, 
        position: 'bottom center', 
        relative: true,
        events: {
              def:     ",",    // default show/hide events for an element
              input:   ",",               // for all    input elements
              widget:  ",",  // select, checkbox, radio, button
              tooltip: ","     // the tooltip element
              },
        onBeforeShow: function() {
        document.getElementById("cog_img").classList.toggle('inactive_cog_img');
        document.getElementById("cog_img").classList.toggle('active_cog_img');
        },
        onHide: function() {
        document.getElementById("cog_img").classList.toggle('inactive_cog_img');
        document.getElementById("cog_img").classList.toggle('active_cog_img');
        }
        });
    tooltip.click(function() {
        var tip = $(this).data("tooltip");
        if (tip.isShown(true))
            tip.hide();
        else
            tip.show();
    });


});
```

Where 
`#cog` is the trigger,
`usermenu` is the tooltip DIV

to see it live i made an example page:
http://test.theshananway.com/test.html (see the cog wheel on the top right)

Please help me find a way to make it work in IE, or let me know if there is an IE alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: I managed to make it work by removing "opacity:0;" from the inline style of your usermenu div. However you will have problem with the arrow covering you cog icon, making it hard to hide the tooltip)

Comment: I have no manual control over the inline opacity, since the jquery plugin effect is the one changing it. Is there any way around?

Answer (score 0):

IE Doesn't like that .classList property... Try this:

```
$('#cog_img').toggleClass("inactive_cog_img").toggleClass("active_cog_img");
```

Instead of this:

```
document.getElementById("cog_img").classList.toggle('inactive_cog_img');
document.getElementById("cog_img").classList.toggle('active_cog_img');
```

Comment: I've update the script in the the example page. Didn't seem to fix it =(